# Grab all instances of pattern from single line of text, edit, pipe out to line-separated text file

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I have a block of text (single line) that is a list of URLs separated by tags and a bunch of other junk. I want to parse that whole block for URLs that match 'http.*">RSS', edit all the instances of that pattern (to get rid of everything after the glob), and pipe the whole thing out to a file as line-separated entries.

I thought I could do this with GREP (then edit and add new lines with SED), but GREP grabs matching lines, not matching *patterns.* Is there a different command I should be using? I've also tried using SED to add a newline (\n) ahead of the pattern wherever it occurs but that's not working either.

Edit: Here's an example of the data that I'm working with:

```
OUT</a> (<a href="https://evilcakes.wordpress.com/rss">RSS</a>)</li><li><a href="http://eater.com/" title="">Eater National</a> (<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/EaterNational">RSS</a>)</li><li><a href="http://www.foodtechconnect.com" title="">Food+Tech Connect</a> (<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/foodtechconnect">RSS</a>)</li><li><a href="http://www.innatthecrossroads.com" title="">Inn at the Crossroads</a> (<a href="http://innatthecrossroads.com/feed/">RSS</a>)</li><li><a href="http://www.seriouseats.com/" title="">Serious Eats</a> (<a href="http://feeds.seriouseats.com/seriouseatsfeaturesvideos">RSS</a>)</li><li><a href="http://www.thatsnerdalicious.com" title="">That's Nerdalicious!</a> (<a href="http://www.thatsnerdalicious.com/feed/">RSS</a>)</li><li><a href="http://thedrunkenmoogle.com/" title="">The Drunken Moogle</a> (<a href="http://www.thedrunkenmoogle.com/rss">RSS</a>)</li></ul></li><li><h2 class="entry-title">Comics</h2><ul class="opmlGroup"><li><a
```

Comment: i would recommend awk. and it would be good if you provide sample data that we can experiment so we're able to give definite answer. however i believe this should go to [superuser stackexchange](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Thanks. Just updated with sample data. I only want the URLs that are directly followed by ">RSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU grep`:

```
grep -oP 'http[^"]*(?=">RSS)' file
```

Results:

```
https://evilcakes.wordpress.com/rss
http://feeds.feedburner.com/EaterNational
http://feeds.feedburner.com/foodtechconnect
http://innatthecrossroads.com/feed/
http://feeds.seriouseats.com/seriouseatsfeaturesvideos
http://www.thatsnerdalicious.com/feed/
http://www.thedrunkenmoogle.com/rss
```

The options:

```
-o, --only-matching
    Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such 
    part on a separate output line.
-P, --perl-regexp
    Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression. This is highly experimental
    and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

Also, you may like to read up on [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). HTH.

***EDIT:***

Here's another way using `awk`:

```
awk -F\" '{ for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($(i+1) ~ /RSS/) print $i }' file
```

Results:

```
https://evilcakes.wordpress.com/rss
http://feeds.feedburner.com/EaterNational
http://feeds.feedburner.com/foodtechconnect
http://innatthecrossroads.com/feed/
http://feeds.seriouseats.com/seriouseatsfeaturesvideos
http://www.thatsnerdalicious.com/feed/
http://www.thedrunkenmoogle.com/rss
```

Comment: This looks great, but it's not working for me. I have BSD grep 2.5.1, though. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @jefflovejapan: Sorry have been away for a little while, please see the edit I've made above. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/https\?:[^"]*/!d;s//\n&\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;P;D' file
```

Comment: @steve Ooops! Yes that command should delete upto and including the first newline. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I put your sample data in urls.dat.

```
cat urls.dat | awk '{n=split($0,a,"\""); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if ( match( a[i], "^http" ) ) print a[i]; }'
```

Comment: It seems like wanting to split a line into multiple lines is not an unusual dilemma. Using awk+split is the best thing I know of. That is until I just learned about grep's -o option. Nice.

Comment: +1 for effort (I'm feeling generous). But this doesn't actually check to see if the address is preceded by 'RSS'. See my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that works with GNU and BSD grep:

```
<infile grep -Eo 'https?://[^"]+">RSS*' | grep -Eo '^[^"]+'
```

Output:

```
https://evilcakes.wordpress.com/rss
http://feeds.feedburner.com/EaterNational
http://feeds.feedburner.com/foodtechconnect
http://innatthecrossroads.com/feed/
http://feeds.seriouseats.com/seriouseatsfeaturesvideos
http://www.thatsnerdalicious.com/feed/
http://www.thedrunkenmoogle.com/rss
```